# Can't add an add-on to my alfresco server 4.2.f

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, reset-password

(Sorry for my english)

I'm trying to install the add-on: https://github.com/share-extras/reset-password-dialog. I do what it says to do to install it:

- I put the "reset-password-dialog-2.0.1.jar" file in: `/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/shared/lib/`
- I then restart the alfresco server by doing:

  /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/alfresco.sh stop

  /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/alfresco.sh start

After the restart there should be a link to reset my password on the login screen but I don't see it

I've tried to activate the add-on by going on the module deployment page but on it I only see "Alfresco portlet extension" in available module

I have also tried to put the file in different directory like: `/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/lib/` and `/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/`

Is this the correct way to add an add-on ?

Comment: Try to put it under /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/lib/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin which you are using is not designed for the latest version or version which you are using.There are some files which are changed in alfresco version 4.2f.I have designed new solution which is compatible with your version.There may be some designing issue, but you can change it in `login.get.html.ftl` file.Functionality is working.I will soon update changes in git repo.

Git location for this project is as below.
    https://github.com/krutik-jayswal/alfresco-solutions/tree/master/reset-password-dialog.